# NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module 'request'

Tags: reactjs, signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

I am developing asp.net core 2.1 with react and implement **@aspnet/signalr**.using **new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(url).build()** In development its working fine when I publish to iis its show error.

error :

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error:
>   Cannot find module 'request' Require stack:
>   - C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js
>   - C:\Windows\TEMP\vo3ipy1u.zpp
>   - C:\Windows\TEMP\esrxoqv2.k4x at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15) at Function.Module._load
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27) at Module.require
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19) at require
>   (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18) at Object.
>   (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:62764:21) at
>   **webpack_require** (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30) at
>   Object.
>   (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:36581:24) at
>   **webpack_require** (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30) at
>   Object.
>   (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:63291:27) at
>   **webpack_require** (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
>   Current directory is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance.InvokeExportAsync(NodeInvocationInfo
>   invocationInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

package.json

```
  {
    "name": "portal",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "@types/history": "4.6.2",
        "@types/i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^2.0.1",
        "@types/immutability-helper": "^2.6.3",
        "@types/react": "^16.8.10",
        "@types/react-dom": "16.0.5",
        "@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.3",
        "@types/react-redux": "5.0.15",
        "@types/react-router": "4.0.23",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.6",
        "@types/react-router-redux": "5.0.12",
        "@types/react-select": "^1.2.7",
        "@types/react-toggle": "^4.0.1",
        "@types/reactstrap": "5.0.20",
        "@types/webpack": "2.2.15",
        "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
        "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
        "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
        "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
        "bxslider": "4.2.11",
        "core-js": "^2.5.7",
        "css-loader": "0.28.4",
        "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.16",
        "domain-task": "^3.0.3",
        "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
        "file-loader": "0.11.2",
        "flot": "0.8.0-alpha",
        "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
        "fullcalendar": "3.4.0",
        "gmaps": "0.4.24",
        "history": "4.6.3",
        "immutability-helper": "^2.7.0",
        "ionicons": "2.0.1",
        "jquery": "3.2.1",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "morris.js": "0.5.0",
        "node-noop": "1.0.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
        "query-string": "6.1.0",
        "raphael": "2.2.7",
        "react": "^16.6.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.6.1",
        "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7",
        "react-redux": "5.0.7",
        "react-router": "^4.3.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
        "reactstrap": "^5.0.0",
        "redux": "3.7.1",
        "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
        "slippry": "1.4.0",
        "style-loader": "0.18.2",
        "summernote": "^0.8.10",
        "tslint": "^5.11.0",
        "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.15.0",
        "tslint-config-standard": "^8.0.1",
        "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
        "twitter-bootstrap-wizard": "1.2.0",
        "typescript": "2.8.1",
        "url-loader": "0.5.9",
        "webpack": "^2.7.0",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
        "webpack-merge": "4.1.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
        "@devexpress/dx-react-core": "^1.2.0",
        "@devexpress/dx-react-grid": "^1.2.0",
        "@devexpress/dx-react-grid-bootstrap4": "^1.2.0",
        "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.42",
        "@types/i18next": "^12.1.0",
        "@types/jsoneditor": "^5.19.0",
        "@types/query-string": "^6.1.0",
        "@types/react-autocomplete": "^1.8.4",
        "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^10.0.3",
        "@types/react-color": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/react-copy-to-clipboard": "^4.2.6",
        "@types/react-flags-select": "^1.1.2",
        "@types/react-redux-toastr": "^7.0.11",
        "@types/reactcss": "^1.2.3",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
        "devextreme": "^18.2.5",
        "devextreme-react": "^18.2.5",
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
        "i18next": "^12.1.0",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^2.2.4",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
        "jsoneditor": "^5.26.2",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.17",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
        "react-autocomplete": "^1.8.1",
        "react-beautiful-dnd": "^10.0.4",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.4",
        "react-color": "^2.17.2",
        "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
        "react-dnd": "^7.0.2",
        "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^7.0.2",
        "react-event-timeline": "^1.6.3",
        "react-i18next": "^9.0.2",
        "react-json-editor-ajrm": "^2.5.8",
        "react-loading-overlay": "^1.0.1",
        "react-moment": "^0.7.6",
        "react-redux-toastr": "^7.2.6",
        "react-select": "^1.2.1",
        "react-sortable-hoc": "^1.7.1",
        "react-spinners": "^0.6.1",
        "react-toggle": "^4.0.2",
        "react-transition-group": "^2.3.1",
        "redbox-react": "^1.6.0"
    } }
```

Comment: @aspnet/signalr has 'request' module in its dependencies make sure you install all dependencies in your prod environment.

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra thanks for the reply, I have installed all dependencies and where we install dependencies for prod enviroment

Comment: in prod run npm install --production, in your project directory. It will install only dependencies skip devDependencies.

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra still error